# Prettify sql output sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, pretty-print

I would like to find a package which structures and make SQL output more readable.

For example there is a package Pretty JSON for json files.
But I would like to have something that make the spaces between columns the same for rows.

```
x   true    SOME_LONG_OUTPUT_WHICH_DESTROYS_THE_ORDER   NULL    
y   true     Short_output   NULL
```

What I would like is something like below:

```
x   true    SOME_LONG_OUTPUT_WHICH_DESTROYS_THE_ORDER   NULL    
y   true    short_output                                NULL
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [AlignTab](https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab) plugin.

To prettify your example, I pasted your text into Sublime Text 3, pressed Ctrl-Shift-P, typed align to select AlignTab, and typed \s+ into the regex to align by spaces and it did what you wanted.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your tinme and input.
It kind of works, but I have a edge case.

For example if I have a cell with soaces in the output, it will be seperated for each space. Might be tough to get around :(

Comment: I can't find this package